# Operand should contain 1 column(s) in the MySql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and displaying the current month data with the group by. I am using below query.

```
$month="MONTH(date_of_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())";
$group="f_id IN (SELECT MAX(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus GROUP BY f_bankid)";

if(($this->session->userdata['login_session']['access_role']==1) || ($this->session->userdata['login_session']['access_role']==2)){
   $or_where="leadstatus='1' AND is_leadConfirm='1' AND ".$month;
}
else{
      $or_where="leadstatus='1'  AND createby='".$this->session->userdata['login_session']['id']."' AND ".$month;
}

$query="select 
         (SELECT COUNT(c_id) FROM tbl_lead WHERE ".$or_where." ) as confirmCount, 
         (SELECT COUNT(doc_id) FROM tbl_documentsPickup WHERE d_pickupStatus=1 ) as docCount, 
         (SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=1 and ".$month." and ".$group.") as a, 
         (SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=2 and ".$month." and ".$group.") as b, 
         (SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=3 and ".$month." and ".$group.") as c, 
         (SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=4 and ".$month." and  ".$group.") as d";
```

I am getting the output which is correct.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [confirmCount] => 1
            [docCount] => 1
            [a] => 0
            [b] => 0
            [c] => 2
            [d] => 0
        )

)
```

Now, I have two doubts

1) Is the above query is the best? Is there any other easy way?

2) I have to change this subquery

```
(SELECT COUNT(doc_id) FROM tbl_documentsPickup WHERE d_pickupStatus=1 ) as docCount
```

to

```
(SELECT (SELECT COUNT(doc_id) FROM tbl_documentsPickup WHERE d_pickupStatus=1) as doc_comp, (SELECT COUNT(doc_id) FROM tbl_documentsPickup WHERE d_pickupStatus=2) as doc_online) as docCount
```

So that I will get output like (This is my expected output)

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [confirmCount] => 1
            [docCount] =>(
                        [doc_comp] => 1
                        [doc_online] => 1
                        ),
            [a] => 0
            [b] => 0
            [c] => 2
            [d] => 0
        )

)
```

I tried the below query but I am getting this issue. I know I am getting more than one column but can you help me with correct query?

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
$query="select 
         (SELECT COUNT(c_id) FROM tbl_lead WHERE ".$or_where." ) as confirmCount, 
         (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(doc_id) FROM tbl_documentsPickup WHERE d_pickupStatus=1) as doc_comp, (SELECT COUNT(doc_id) FROM tbl_documentsPickup WHERE d_pickupStatus=2) as doc_online) as docCount, 
         (SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=1 and ".$month." and ".$group.") as a, 
         (SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=2 and ".$month." and ".$group.") as b, 
         (SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=3 and ".$month." and ".$group.") as c, 
         (SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=4 and ".$month." and  ".$group.") as d";
```

Comment: you cant't do that for mysql there are 2 columns an you can have only 1, So make a json in mysql or do it in codeigniter

Comment: @nbk, Can you suggest me json? or any example?

Answer (score 0):

Json is only text:

so you can do this

```
select CONCAT('{ doc_comp: '
             ,(SELECT COUNT(c_id) FROM tbl_lead WHERE ".$or_where." )
            ,', docCount: { confirmCount : '
            ,(SELECT COUNT(c_id) FROM tbl_lead WHERE ".$or_where." )
            ,', doc_comp : '
            ,(SELECT COUNT(doc_id) FROM tbl_documentsPickup WHERE d_pickupStatus=1)
            ,' } }, a : '
            , (SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=1 and ".$month." and ".$group.")
            ,', b : '
            ,(SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=1 and ".$month." and ".$group.")
            ,' c : '
            , (SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=3 and ".$month." and ".$group.")
            ,' d :'
            ,(SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus WHERE f_filestatus=4 and ".$month." and  ".$group.") 
            ,'}');
```

As you didn't provide data, i didn't test the json, so you should test it in jsonlint

Comment: Give me some time to check the query

Comment: I need to know why you started from { doc_comp:.  I have to change the second subquery

Comment: I have to change this query :(SELECT COUNT(doc_id) FROM tbl_documentsPickup WHERE d_pickupStatus=1 ) as docCount

Comment: first you get such an json file https://phrase.com/de/docs/guides/formats/nested-json/ and please edit my code if i had an error in it

Comment: doccount is the base elemment for the nested json in your given example